# Javascript and Java Communication

Tags: javascript, java, parameter-passing, oracle-adf

I am building application using `ADF` technology with `Jdeveloper 11.1.2.3` as IDE. In the application in some `jspx` page I am having `<OBJECT>` tag where the user can insert special type of input(digital signature). This tag data is accessible in the `jspx` page through `Javascript` function. The problem is : **How can I access the variables that define in the `Javascript` function(which hold the digital signature data) through the Java class `BackingBean`(NOT `Servlet`).**

This is the `<OBJECT>` tag and the buttons that call the `Javascript` function:
Note: I am sure that the `Javascript` hold the data needed(digital signature object) and this not all the functions I have.

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:69A40DA3-4D42-11D0-86B0-0000C025864A" height="75" border="2" id="SigPlus1"  
                    name="SigPlus1" style="HEIGHT: 180px; WIDTH: 320px; LEFT: 0px; TOP: 0px;">  
              <param name="_Version" value="131095"/>  
              <param name="_ExtentX" value="4842"/>  
              <param name="_ExtentY" value="1323"/>  
              <param name="_StockProps" value="0"/>  
            </OBJECT>  

 <INPUT id="submit1" name="Save" type="submit" value="Save" onclick="OnSave()"/>
```

I tried the following approach but it is not working:

I added a hidden filed in the page like and bind the value property of the `hidden input` to an attribute in the java `BackingBean` as follow:

```
<input type="hidden" id="passSignToBean" value="${SRdetailsBean.sigObj}"/>
```

and this is the `Javascript` function that will change the input filed value:

```
function OnSave() {

document.forms[0].SigPlus1.TabletState = 0; //Turns tablet off
document.forms[0].SigPlus1.SigCompressionMode = 2; //Compresses the signature at a 2.5 to 1 ratio, making it smaller...to display the signature again later, you WILL HAVE TO set the SigCompressionMode of the new SigPlus object = 1, also

alert("Test 1");

document.getElementById('passSignToBean').value = document.forms[0].SigPlus1;

alert("Test 2");
}
```

My idea is that when the user click on submit button the `Javascript` function  `OnSave()` will be called and change the value of the `hidden input` tag. Since, I am binding this input filed to some attribute in the java `BacknigBean` (I am assuming) the attribute in the bean should be updated to match the new value of the `hidden input` filed.

Important Note:
I am Not using `HttpServlet`.
I am not using java `applet`.

When I am trying this approach I got `NullPointerException` when I am trying to use the java `BackingBean` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't mix HTML and ADF.
If you need to talk to call server side method from javascript, you have to queue server event.
Check this documentation with samples:
http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/tagdoc/af_serverListener.html

Basicaly, you generate server event that you catch with listener in the backing bean and pass your variable as parameter to this event.

And there how you call javascript method from bean:

```
FacesContext fctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExtendedRenderKitService service = Service.getRenderKitService(fctx, extendedRenderKitService.class);
service.addScript(fctx, "<any javascript to be invoked>");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nagh, that's exactly what I need. But, How can I do it the other way back;that is, how can I pass data from Java method to Javascript function.